# I am running command "terraform init" but getting this error, while in other folder within same machine this command is working perectly

Tags: terraform

I am running command "terraform init" but getting this error, while in other folder within same machine this command is working perectly and also other terraform command is also working.

```
Error while installing terraform-aws-modules/http v2.4.1: could not query
provider registry for registry.terraform.io/terraform-aws-modules/http: failed
to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the request failed after 2
attempts, please try again later: Get
"https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-provider-http/releases/download/v2.4.1/terraform-provider-http_2.4.1_SHA256SUMS":
context deadline exceeded
```

Comment: Are you behind a Proxy/Vpn? Can you try to open the registry to see if it works? Maybe changing your DNS can help too.